# Using a static var in a thread as communication among different instances

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a multi-threaded batch processing app that runs anywhere between 5-10 concurrent threads of execution.  Their data segments are carefully sliced to be as evenly distributed as possible but, of course, the execution times always vary.  What I wanna do is to invoke one last kind of onFinalize method when the last thread finishes, which will do some stat computation.

I was wondering if the best way to know for a thread that it is the last one (rather than querying the DB, which seems kind of pedestrian) is to have a static var which would be incremented in a synchronized block when a new thread is added and decremented when each thread finishes.  So when a thread finishes and does its decrementing, I can have an if to see if the outstanding # of threads is 0 and then invoke the final stats.

That is what I was thinking.  I was wondering if there is a better, more elegant, or bulletproof way of accomplishing this.

Using Java 7

Thanks

Comment: That should work, though so would an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Or perhaps [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) See the example in the javadocs, i think it does exactly what you want

Comment: thanks.  what confuses me is that i cannot use a synchronized block within the run() impl.  so my concern is thread safety -- if i just leave the var declaration as private static int, will it be thread safe?  or, the better i think, does thread safety even matter here?

Comment: @foampile without the memory barriers ensured by a `synchronized` block or making it `volatile`, it is not guaranteed that writes will be visible to other threads.

Comment: @foampile you should really just use a `CountDownLatch` like the commenter above suggested.

Comment: thanks.  i was thinking about volatile too.

Comment: yes -- CountDownLatch is the way to go.  THANKS A LOT !!

Comment: Thread safety is very important, and one thing to be cognizant of is `Thread` death resulting in waiting forever, or completely inaccurate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what else you can do is that you can create a `ThreadManager` class. This class should have a `List<Thread>`. Whenever you create a new `Thread` to execute your task you should `register` it in `ThreadManager`. Then create a method in `ThreadManager` which returns the total `number` of `live Threads` in the `List`.

In this way you can at any point see how many threads are running and also you can perform any other operation on the running threads if you want. Also one more `Thread` should run periodically which should clear all dead Thread references from the `List`.

Sample `ThreadManager` can look like this:

```
public class ThreadManager {
    private static ThreadManager tm;
    private List<Thread> threads;

    public static ThreadManager get() {
        if(null == tm) {
            tm = new ThreadManager();
        }

        return tm;
    }

    private ThreadManager() {
        threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    }

    public int getCountOfAliveThreads() {
        int count = 0;
        for(Thread t : threads) {
            if(t.isAlive()) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. You can perform other functions aswell on the `Thread List`.

Comment: You could completely avoid writing any code for the above solution by using an `ExecutorService` and call `shutdown`, and then wait until it returns `true` for `isShutdown`. You could monitor the `Future`s for completeness (see `submit`), if you care about them individually (for counts and such), and if you don't, then you're done by busy waiting on `isShutdown` above, which is not any different than what the above `ThreadManager` will introduce, but in next to no code.

Comment: @pickypg - +1 for 'completely avoid writing any code for the above solution' - that's pretty much a good answer on its own.  Thread micro-management is a spectacularly easy way to get into a big mess :((

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call Thread.join() on each thread at the end? You can have a for loop to call it on each - it will lock on the first running, then when that one completes, return and you then lock on the next running. When you exit the loop, they've all exited.

```
public class ThreadManager {
    private List<Thread> threads;

    public void addThread(Thread thread) {
        threads.add(thread);
    }

    public void waitTillAllComplete() {
        for (int ind=0; ind<threads.size(); ind++)
            threads.get(ind).join();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my solution is the least work - it's 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar by creating a framework that extends the basic `Runnable` interface to provide a more robust threading architecture. I later discovered that it was amazingly similar to asynchronous code in GWT for similar purposes.

This is from memory, but it basically boils down to:

```
public interface AsyncRunnable<T> extends Runnable
{
    AsyncCallback<T> getCallback();

    T runAsync();
}

public interface AsyncCallback<T>
{
    void onSuccess(T data);
    void onFailure(Exception exception);
}

public interface AsyncCallbackInvoker<T> extends Runnable
{
    // implies requirement for callback...
    AsyncCallback<T> getCallback();
}

public class SuccessfulAsyncCallbackInvoker<T> implements AsyncCallback<T>
{
    private final AsyncCallback<T> callback;
    private final T data;

    public SuccessfulAsyncCallbackInvoker(AsyncCallback<T> callback, T data)
    {
        // note: data being null may be valid; callback would not be

        this.callback = callback;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        callback.onSuccess(data);
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncCallback<T> getCallback()
    {
        return callback;
    }
}

public class FailureAsyncCallbackInvoker<T> implements AsyncCallback<T>
{
    private final AsyncCallback<T> callback;
    private final Exception  exception;

    public FailureAsyncCallbackInvoker(AsyncCallback<T> callback, Exception exception)
    {
        // note: data being null may be valid; callback would not be

        this.callback = callback;
        this.exception= exception;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        callback.onFailure(exception);
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncCallback<T> getCallback()
    {
        return callback;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractAsyncRunnable<T> implements AsyncRunnable<T>
{
    private final AsyncCallback<T> callback;

    public AbstractAsyncRunnable(AsyncCallback<T> callback)
    {
        // if == null -> throw

        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public /* final */ void run()
    {
        AsyncCallbackInvoker<T> invoker;

        try
        {
            T data = runAsync();

            invoker = new SuccessfulAsyncCallbackInvoker<T>(callback, data);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            invoker = new FailureAsyncCallbackInvoker<T>(callback, e);
        }

        invokeCallback(invoker);
    }

    // allows overriding to put callback on whatever Thread you want
    protected void invokeCallback(AsyncCallbackInvoker<T> invoker)
    {
        invoker.run();
    }
}
```

In practice, it has proven to be incredibly robust, and particularly by providing the ability to override `invokeCallback` has enabled us to leverage a lot of thread safe operations with guaranteed responses.

In practice, implementations then only have to override the `runAsync` method of `AsyncRunnable` and provide whatever `AsyncCallback` that they see fit. It's important to note that there are occasions when you really use it for a means of simply marking completion, and in such cases `T` can be `Void` (`return null` from `runAsync` if you use that).

Answer (score -1):

I appreciate all the super useful and enlightening answers, however, the simple counter with static and volatile seems to work fine:

```
private static volatile int crntThrdCnt = 0;
```

and then

```
    @Override
public void run() 
{
    crntThrdCnt++;
    this.runBatchInstance();
    crntThrdCnt--;

    if(crntThrdCnt == 0)
    {
        ProcessManager prcsMgr = new ProcessManager();
        Batch batch = prcsMgr.getBatch(this.batchID);
        batch.setEndTime(new Date());
        prcsMgr.updateBatch(batch);
    }
}
```

Comment: If any of your `Runnable`s do not run exactly in parallel, then you will end up running the `ProcessManager` multiple times (this can be at least helped by incrementing `crntThrdCnt` when constructing each `Runnable` rather than when they actually `run`). If `runBatchInstance` throws an `Exception`, then your `ProcessManager` will never be executed.

Comment: -1.  This code is not thread-safe.  Using the increment/decrement operators (++, --) on a volatile variable is not thread-safe.  "seems to work fine": that's the problem with code which is not thread-safe, it will often work fine... until it doesn't.

Comment: Yes - needs atomic inc/dec or lock.