# Multiple threads and Synchronization in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a multithreaded program where each thread calculates the GCD for two numbers,  stores the numbers and GCD into a `TreeMap`, and prints out the `TreeMap` after all the threads finish. What kind of method should I use to make sure that only one thread is storing the data at the same time, and how do I use the last thread to print the `TreeMap` when it is ready to print?

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < myList.size(); ++j) {
        modulus1 = myList.get(i);
        modulus2 = myList.get(j);
        pool.execute(new ThreadProcessRunnable(modulus1, modulus2, myMap));
    }
}

public void run() {
    ThreadProcess process = null;
    try {
        // Only one thread should execute the following code
        for (Map.Entry<BigInteger, ArrayList<BigInteger>> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("key ->" + entry.getKey() + ", value->" + entry.getValue());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception ERROR");
    }
```

Comment: [Synchronize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) the method(s) that access the data

Comment: It appears that your `for` loop should only be an `if` check? `List<BigInteger> list = myMap.get(FirstModulus); if (list == null) { list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>(); myMap.put(FirstModulus, list); } list.add(gcd);` (this eliminates the need for the `if (myMap.size() > 0) { ... } else { ... }` and makes it a bit more readable)

Comment: Have a look at thread communication discussions like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274821/using-a-static-var-in-a-thread-as-communication-among-different-instances

Answer (score 1):

You must use `syncronize(myMap) {...}` block in places where you need to guarantee single thread access to the map.

As for printing the result by the last thread, you can use a boolean flag as a signal of completeness and check it every time. Don't forget to make it `volatile` to let each thread see its value changes.

**UPD:** Brian Goetz "Java Concurrency In Practice" is a strongly recommended reading.

Comment: Thanks. the boolean flag works inside each thread? where should check the condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
          //Only one thread should executes the following code
synchronize{            
for (Map.Entry<BigInteger, ArrayList<BigInteger>> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("key ->" + entry.getKey() + ", value->" + entry.getValue());
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collections.synchronizedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) to make it thread safe. And use [thread.join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) to make sure printing is done only when all threads are dead.

**Edit:** Do the printing in Main thread. Just before printing, call `join` on all threads.

Comment: The same issue relates to this as Quoi's solution.

Comment: Join waits for the thread to die. How do I know when all the thread finished.